how can I solve equation of multi-variables raised to themselves?
I have this problem from Math Kangaroo 2024 sample questions:
A special four-digit number $\overline {abcd}$ satisfies the equation: $\overline {abcd} = a^{a} + b^{b} + c^{c} + d^{d}$. What is the value of $a$?
I tried some simple algebra:
$10^{3}a + 10^{2}b + 10c + d = a^{a} + b^{b} + c^{c} + d^{d}$
$a( a^{a-1} - 1000 ) + b( b^{b-1} - 100 ) + c( c^{c-1} - 10 ) ) + d(d^{d-1} - 1) = 0$
and because $a, b, c, d$ are positive integer each term must equal $0$, and I know that $a, b, c, d$ can't be $0$, in other word "$a, b, c, d > 0$", so I can write "sub-equations" like:
$a^{a-1} = 1000$
$b^{b-1} = 100$
$c^{c-1} = 10$
$d^{d-1} = 1$
now, I can easily conclude that $d$ is $1$ (there no other solutions because $d$ is integer), so I can remove it from the original equation :
$10^{3}a + 10^{2}b + 10c = a^{a} + b^{b} + c^{c}$
I tried to divide both sides by $10$ to isolate $c$ again but it doesn't work, what ever I do it's an equation!!
if anyone has an idea to get the other variables, I'm listening.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

Please don't use pictures, and use MathJax to format equations. I edited your question for you this time; in the future please do so yourself when asking a question.

I don't agree with your conclusion that each term in the rearranged equation has to equal $0$. Some could be positive, some negative, and cancel each other out. In fact, e.g. $c^{c-1}=10$ has no integer solution, so this is definitely not correct.

@anankElpis yes, you are  absolutely right but I think that $a,b,c,d$ are digits which can't be negative or none integer, right?

Each term of the form $a_i(a_i^{a_i-1}-10^i)$ doesn't necessarily equal to $0$, where $a_3=a$, $a_2=b$, $a_1=c$, and $a_0=d$. However, you can utilize other constraints. Such as $6^6>9999$, hence none of $a_i$ can be $6$ or greater. This brings you down to about $1296$ candidate numbers, which can be further shortlisted by conditions like the number must contain the digit $5$ at least once, since $4^4=256$ and $4444 > 4^4+4^4+4^4+4^4$.
With some guesses you can get to an answer of $3435=3^3+4^4+3^3+5^5$, which is a decent method for an Olympiad-style number theory problem.

Great dealing, I really thrilled  with your algebraic escapade that went beyond this annoying algebra to simplify the problem and get a perfect solution, thanks
